# OWASP ZAP Proxy script based authentication - How to automate

Tags: docker, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, owasp, zap

I am trying to automate the docker implementation of [ZAP proxy](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/full-scan/) to target some of my token based web applications, which use Amazon Cognito for authentication and authorization.

Since, the target app need token as `Authorization` header, on ZAP Desktop application it can be done through "`Authentication`" and "`HttpSender`" scripts for fetching token from Cognito and placing it in each HTTP request of the URLs being scanned respectively.

However, for ZAP Docker, I can send a context file to it using "-n" flag, the file will also contain a reference to the "Authentication" script that I would create to fetch the token from Cognito. But I do not find a way to bind "HttpSender" script with context file or any flag that takes this file from the provided list of options given in the link above.

So, the questions are:

1. Can I use additional libraries such as AWS SDK to refer within Authentication script? How can I pass them to the ZAP Docker container so that the script can reference it at runtime?
2. Is there a way to send HttpSender script, or any other way, to put the token in each scan request?

Thanks!

Comment: This has been replied and commented here as well: https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-develop/c/mGw2we8fcIk

Comment: I saw your post in google group but I could not find the blog post. Did you create a tutorial on how to do this? If you can post here a working example (as simple as possible showing requests and global variable settings and integration with ZAP CLI and GUI) that would be very helpful and appreciated.